How to update a component field for a single player for all player views?
I'm making a 2 player game in which, when 2 players are in a room, they "toss a coin" to decide which of the two player "skins" they get.
Now, the way I built the player "skins" is as such: I drew the sprite sheets myself, and then made an animation of each motion (walking right, walking left, back, idle, etc) and I used a blend tree in the animator controller to switch between them according to input. I have saved an animator controller as such for each "skin" and so I thought - instead of having two player prefabs, I will have one player prefab. I will instantiate it and then just change its animator controller to the right one! easy, right?
Well, not so much when you're working across several game instances.
Apparently, when I change the animator controller right after creation, it changes the view in that same player instance, but the other player does not see anything different, they only see the default one.
I am trying to find a way to update it. I thought of maybe doing it via RPC, but I can't get it to work.
Here is my code, I'd love some help.
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public GameObject PlayerPrefab;

    //player sprites animator  controllers (essentially also control which sprites are used so represent different player skins)
    public RuntimeAnimatorController[] AnimatorControllers;
    
    public GameObject SceneCamera;
    [SerializeField] private int playerMax = 2;

    //list of nuumbers representing available player skins. (list in case I want to add more player skins.)
    private List<int> playerSpriteAssignmentNumbers = new List<int> { 0, 1 };
    private Dictionary<int, int> playerNumberMap = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    //private int playerSkinNumber;
    

    void Start()
    {
        //if player is master of the match (started the match)
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            // Shuffle the available numbers to randomize which player gets which player skin
            ShuffleList(playerSpriteAssignmentNumbers);
            if (playerSpriteAssignmentNumbers.Count > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("assigning number");
                int assignedNumber = playerSpriteAssignmentNumbers[0];
                Debug.Log("assigned number is: !" + assignedNumber);
                playerSpriteAssignmentNumbers.RemoveAt(0);
                photonView.RPC("AddToplayerNumberDictionary", RpcTarget.All, assignedNumber, PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    // shuffle a list
    void ShuffleList<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = Random.Range(0, n + 1);
            (list[n], list[k]) = (list[k], list[n]);
        }
    }



    // Called when a new player joins
    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {

        //if player is master of the match
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            //assign newly entered player a skin number and delete it from the list. 
            if (playerSpriteAssignmentNumbers.Count > 0)
            {
                int assignedNumber = playerSpriteAssignmentNumbers[0];
                playerSpriteAssignmentNumbers.RemoveAt(0);
                photonView.RPC("AddToplayerNumberDictionary", RpcTarget.All,assignedNumber,newPlayer.ActorNumber);
             
                // Send the assigned number to the new player
               //photonView.RPC("SetPlayerNumber", newPlayer, assignedNumber);
               // Debug.Log("sent number");
            }
        }
        if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == playerMax)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ready!");
            //start countdown and game.
            StartCoroutine("ReadyDelay");
            /*if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
                photonView.RPC("ReadyGame", RpcTarget.All);*/
        }
        else if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount < playerMax)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waiting for PLayers");

            //add canvas text here
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ReadyDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
            photonView.RPC("ReadyGame", RpcTarget.All);

    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void ReadyGame()
    {
        SpawnPlayer();
        SceneCamera.SetActive(false);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void AddToplayerNumberDictionary(int assignedNumber,int actorNumber) 
    {
        playerNumberMap[actorNumber] = assignedNumber;
    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void AssignAnimatorController( Animator animator, int actorNumber)
    {
        animator.runtimeAnimatorController = AnimatorControllers[playerNumberMap[actorNumber]];
    }

    /* [PunRPC]
     void SetPlayerNumber(int assignedNumber)
     {

         Debug.Log($"Player {PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber} has number {assignedNumber}");
         //save the  master-assigned skin number
         playerSkinNumber = assignedNumber;
     }*/



    public void SpawnPlayer()
    {
        Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3( Random.Range(-1f,1f), Random.Range(-1f, 1f),0);
        GameObject newPlayer =  PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(PlayerPrefab.name, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity, 0);
        Animator animator = newPlayer.GetComponent<Animator>();
       // animator.runtimeAnimatorController = AnimatorControllers[playerSkinNumber];

        int localPlayerActorNumber = PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber;

        if (playerNumberMap.ContainsKey(localPlayerActorNumber))
        {
            //photonView.RPC("AssignAnimatorController", RpcTarget.All, animator, localPlayerActorNumber);
            animator.runtimeAnimatorController = AnimatorControllers[playerNumberMap[localPlayerActorNumber]];
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Assigned number not found for this player.");
        }
    }


}

